# authentication of users cake php

Tags: cakephp

4 I have an application that registers users to edit and write on a page.My problem is once the first user logs in all the other users seem not to need a valid password.In short it will only authenticate the first user.
The add action is used to registered new users,the blog action is the edit and posting page.I appreciate any help thanks.

Below are my codes;

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public $name='Users';
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add','logout'); // Letting users register themselves
}

      public function isAuthorized($user){
       if (in_array($this->action, array('edit'))){
          if($user['id'] != $this->request->params['pass'][0]){
          return false;
          }
       }
          return true;
     }      
       public function login() {
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
         debug($this->Auth->login());
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else{
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'),'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
   } 
 } 
        public function logout() {
             return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
          public function users() {

      }

         public function index() {
          $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));

    }
         public function view($id = NULL) {
          $this->set('users', $this->User->read(NULL, $id));

    }
      public function edit() {

    }
      public function blog() {
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $this->User->create();
       if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
       return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
       }
       }
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('really'));
    }
         public function add() {
             if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();

            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                 $this->request->data['User']['password'] ==$this->request->data['User'][ 'password_Confirmation'];
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `debug($this->Auth->login())` and `if ($this->Auth->login()) {}` don't play well with each other. the first returns true and the second then false. either use die() afterwards to abort or don't debug it this way. Also You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Thanks mark let me try it out

Comment: Hi,That dint seem to solve my problem my app only authenticates the validity of the 1st user.If I use a false password after that all the rest get access to a page without requiring a valid password.Any help